# Как передать данные из js в php скрипт и запустить его?

Tags: php, передача-данных, автозапуск, javascript

как передать данные из js в php скрипт и запустить его?
К примеру, `1.js php-5.php`.

**Обновление**

Там не форма, там таблица. Клацая на нее, значение ячейки переносится в переменную, а переменную по нажатию надо передать в php-файл.

Comment: нет.мне нужно именно в файл пхп

Comment: По стандартному отправить из формы через GET/POST или, что скорее всего вам и надо, воспользоваться AJAX запросом.

Comment: там не форма.там таблица.клацая на нее значение ячейки переносится в переменную.а переменную по нажатию надо передать в php файл

Comment: @florian92, смотрите технологию AJAX запросов.

Comment: @florian92, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

AJAX + PHP: применение, взаимодействие, пример

http://sitear.ru/material/ajax-php#ajax-php-vzaimodeistvie